# Ajax загрука страницы

Tags: ajax

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ajax jQuery</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="content">

    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('nav li a').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        $.ajax({
            url:     url,
            success: function(data){
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
        });

        if(url != window.location){
            window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
        }

        return false;
    });
});
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

при перезагрузци страницы загружает только контент страницы, как сделать чтобы загружало основную страницу и добавляло контент той страницы которую мы загрузили?

Comment: А что сервер возвращает-то?

Comment: как вариант можете дописать в url параметр 1-3, и при перезагрузке сранице уже проверять этот url и симулировать нажатие на нужную вам клавишу.

Comment: если скопировать url и вставить в новом окне, то откроется только контент без хедера и т.п. Как решить эту проблему?